# Resonance level model: Commutator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, fermions, commutator

As a small part of an exercise on the resonant level model (all fermionic (field-)operators, $\Psi(\vec{x}) = \sum\limits_{\vec{k}}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{x}}c_{\vec{k}} $,  $V$ is a constant, $d$ and $c$ commute, etc...)

$$H = \sum\limits_{\vec{k}}\epsilon_{\vec{k}}c^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}c_{\vec{k}} + \epsilon_dd^{\dagger}d + V\Psi^{\dagger}(0)d + V^{*}d^{\dagger}\Psi(0)$$

I should show that: $[\Psi(\vec{x},t), H] = \epsilon_{-i\partial_x}\Psi(\vec{x},t) + \delta(\vec{x})Vd(t)$

---

What I have done:

$$[\Psi(\vec{x},t), H] = [e^{iHt}\Psi(\vec{x})e^{-iHt},H] = e^{iHt}[\Psi(\vec{x}), H]e^{-iHt} $$

$$[\Psi(\vec{x}), H] = \left[\Psi(\vec{x}), \sum\limits_{\vec{k}}\epsilon_{\vec{k}}c^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}c_{\vec{k}}\right] + \left[\Psi(\vec{x}), V\Psi^{\dagger}(0)d \right] $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{\vec{k}, \vec{k'}}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{x}} [c_{\vec{k}}, n_{\vec{k}'
}] +Vd \left[\Psi(\vec{x}), \Psi^{\dagger}(0) \right] $$
$$= \sum\limits_{\vec{k}, \vec{k'}}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{x}} \delta_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'}c_{\vec{k}} +Vd \left( \{\Psi(\vec{x}), \Psi^{\dagger}(0)\} - 2\Psi^{\dagger}(0) \Psi(\vec{x}) \right) $$
$$= \epsilon_{-i\partial_x}\Psi(\vec{x}) + Vd \Big( \delta(\vec{x}) - 2\Psi^{\dagger}(0) \Psi(\vec{x}) \Big) $$

Compared to the proposed solution (after restoring the time-dependency) the term $- 2Vd\Psi^{\dagger}(0) \Psi(\vec{x})$ seems excessive in my solution, yet I don't find any mistake.

What am I missing?!

Comment: Shouldn't $c$ and $d$ anticommute?

Comment: You mean $\{d,c^{\dagger}\}=\delta_{c,d}$? Actually the task doesn't state that. But even with them anti-commuting it does not seem like I will get the mentioned commutation relation?

Answer (score 0):

As a comment suggests, it is likely that in a term that was not written out, you used $[c,d]=0$ instead of $\{c,d\}=0$. The actual commutator is

$$ [\Psi(x), \Psi^\dagger(0)d]=\{\Psi(x),\Psi^\dagger(0)\}d-\Psi^\dagger(0)\{\Psi(x),d\}=\delta(x)d.
$$